# SSLCipherSuite - disable weak encryption, cbc cipher and md5 based algorithm

Tags: ssl, tls

A developer recently ran a PCI Scan with TripWire against our LAMP server.  They identified several issues and instructed the following to correct the issues:

Problem: SSL Server Supports Weak Encryption for SSLv3, TLSv1,

Solution:  Add the following rule to httpd.conf

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
```

Problem: SSL Server Supports CBC Ciphers for SSLv3, TLSv1

Solution: Disable any cipher suites using CBC ciphers

Problem: SSL Server Supports Weak MAC Algorithm for SSLv3, TLSv1

Solution: Disable any cipher suites using MD5 based MAC algorithms

I tried searching google for a comprehensive tutorial on how to construct an SSLCipherSuite directive to meet my requirements, but I didn't find anything I could understand.  I see examples of SSLCipherSuite directives, but I need an explanation on what each component of the directive does.  So even in the directive `SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM`, I dont understand for example what the `!LOW` means.

Can someone either a) tell me the SSLCipherSuite directive that will meet my needs or b) show me a resource that clearly explains each segment of a SSLCipherSuite is and how to construct one?

Comment: By the way - there's no SSL or TLS settings that are widely supports and without *some* level of vulnerability. You *really* need to find someone half way competent with SSL/TLS security, have them take 15 minutes to get familiar with your requirements, and make a recommendation that actually fits your situation. Blindly running TripWire without any ability to interpret the results isn't helping, not really.

Comment: Read their requirements again. You can fix all these problems by simply disable SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If their only complaint is MD5-based MAC, you should be able to simply add the `!MD5` element to your existing cipher suite to meet the recommendation.

That said, I see they complain about the use of the CBC mode as well.  Unfortunately, there is no `CBC` cipher group.  The recommendation given to you also does not exclude CBC mode cipherspecs, at least on my version of openSSL (1.0.1e).  This is a shame.  If you need all such ciphers to be excluded, you could exclude all the CBC ones explicitly, though you will have to update that as they are included.  Note that even `HIGH` includes CBC ciphers.

Including both `ALL` and `RC4+RSA` is redundant.  I would be loathe to trust a security consultant (even a computerized one) that cannot even construct a well-formed cipherspec that meets their own recommendations.

The `SSLCipherSuite` takes an OpenSSL cipher spec.  You can find this [in the openssl documentation (link)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html), but I find that this documentation is usually quite out of date.  However, you can test one by running `openssl ciphers ${cipherspec}` on your server; output will be a `:`-separated list of ciphers that would be allowed by the given spec, or an error indicating none were allowed.

Similarly, if you want to know what `LOW` contains, do:

```
falcon@tiernyn ~ $ openssl ciphers 'LOW'
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:ADH-DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-MD5
```

`!LOW` means to exclude those ones.  `+HIGH` means to prefer the high-security ones in the ordering.

If you want a line-delimited list of all the ciphers that use CBC in your cipherspec, do:

```
openssl ciphers ${cipherspec} | sed 's/:/\n/g' | grep CBC
```

Those are the ones you'd have to exclude.  You may, however, find it more reasonable to `grep -v CBC` and include only those (just set them up in a `:`-delimited list and use that as the cipherspec).

Comment: Thanks Falcon.  I'm trying things out now.  Is there a simple way to test/confirm a rule like !MD5 was successfully applied to my SSL-Apache instance?  I'd google the question myself, but i'm on a bus in china with limited internet access (low on bandwidth and connectivity)

Comment: You could try using `openssl s_client -connect host:port -cipher MD5` to connect to it with `MD5` as the cipher suite, or you could use the Qualys SSL scan (when you have more internet access) to get a very detailed analysis (assuming it is internet-facing).

Comment: Note: grepping on CBC is ok, but not on openssl names only. Use  

    openssl ciphers -V -stdname ${cipherspec} | sed 's/:/\n/g' | grep CBC

This will include the IANA names, see https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml

Comment: Note: grepping on CBC is ok, but not on openssl names only. Use  
```
    openssl ciphers -V -stdname ${cipherspec} | sed 's/:/\n/g' | grep CBC
```
This will include the IANA names, see https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml

Answer (score 4):

The `mod_ssl` documentation explains the components of the `SSLCipherSuite` settings, [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite).

If you want to meet all of those scan requirements, you pretty much need to run just RC4 with `SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA` (or run newer TLS which may or may not be practical for your system).

Comment: Thanks, I actually used this solution instead. and it worked